# Azure VM disables ssh with password

Tags: azure, sshd

I want to create an Azure VM image that allows logging in with a password via SSH. I have an Azure Ubuntu VM, which I configure to allow password SSH (updating /etc/sshd/sshd_config appropriately). I can log into it with ssh properly. However, when I create an image from the VM, and create a VM from the image, logging in with a password is disabled again.

How can I cause Azure not to overwrite /etc/sshd/sshd_config when creating a VM from an image?

Answer (score 0):

Did you choose a supported SSH format? Check this Microsoft guide on how to create and manage SSH keys
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed
Maybe you find some mistakes you've made along the way.

Comment: OP does _not_ want to use keys.